# Find the index of a item in a sorted list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We have a generated list:

```
1. 003
2. 012
3. 021
4. 030
5. 102
6. 111
7. 120
8. 201
9. 210
10. 300
```

(numbers are from 0 to 3 and their sum is 3)

How to find in what place is a combination without counting them??
Ex. 201 -> index=8
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better if it were posted to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: It's more algorithmic, than straight maths, probably best here.

Comment: Eric Lippert did a long series on permutations, which may be of some help. First article is at http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: It's called "binary search".

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. For the more general problem I would have suggested a binary search.

Comment: Yes, the title needs to stress that it is calculating the position in a permutation in a permutation set with a defined order.

Comment: @TC1: I don't think they want to perform a search.  The permutation has a defined order, the individual digits of each permutation are valued and relevant to that order.  It's a mathematical construction of the index from the digits of the permutation.

Comment: @Orbling if you wanna go that way, they're **not** permutations, they're **weak compositions** of 3. He presented it as a list with lexicological ordering, in which case a binary search would find what he needs in O(log N).

Comment: @TC1: Still there is a defined ordering with numerical relationships.  I assume the 3 as a starting point with 3 positions is a trivial example.  The mathematical relationship, which should exist probably has O(1).

Comment: @Orbling The problem states "we **have** a generated list", not "we're generating a list on the fly". Binary search works for any ordered input with a defined comparison operation, which this clearly is.

Comment: @TC1: Well, without the OP commenting, it's hard to know what the intention is.

Answer (score 4):

If digits of your number are ABC, then index is:

```
ndx = A * (8 - A + 1) / 2 + B + 1;
```

For example, for value ABC=201, we will have:

```
ndx = 2 * (8 - 2 + 1) / 2 + 0 + 1 = 8;
```

Really, value 201 has index 8.

Comment: yeah but where did you get the 8 and why have not used the c value??

Comment: if i have a longer combination with another sum how do i get the index. i need a general way of doing this

Comment: C values is unused. It defined by values AB. About 8 -- See formula of sum of arithmetic progression.

Comment: You asked about S=3; so, I answered to this question. For another sums: N = 2 * (S + 1);

Comment: it is not what i am looking about

Comment: Sorry, telepats on vacations

Comment: @Katolog Katolog: Why not? To me, that is the answer to the very question you asked.

Comment: @KatologKatolog, I agree - this is the answer to the question you asked. If it's not what you want, it's because you didn't phrase the question properly.

Comment: +1. Good job. This is exactly what I was trying to come up with in my answer.

Comment: @KatologKatolog: If you look at my answer, you'll see that the C value is irrelevant. You can compute the index based only on the first two digits. This is the answer to the question you asked. If you want some other answer, then you need to ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I think this is a good start.

If you view each digit as two binary digits, you get:

```
 1. 003  00 00 11
 2. 012  00 01 10
 3. 021  00 10 01
 4. 030  00 11 00
 5. 102  01 00 10
 6. 111  01 01 01
 7. 120  01 10 00
 8. 201  10 00 01
 9. 210  10 01 00
10. 300  11 00 00
```

If you ignore the right hand column of digits, then the first seven items (values 003 through 120) are the binary representations of the numbers 0 through 6.

The next two items have values 8 and 9, and the last is 12.

So, we can convert the number to a rough index with:

```
ix = 4*first_digit + second_digit
```

And then adjust:

```
if (first_digit < 2)
    ix = ix + 1
else if (first_digit == 3)
    ix = ix - 2
```

I'm not happy with the conditional there. Is there a mathematical way to make this translation:

```
0 => 1
1 => 1
2 => 0
3 => -2
```

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to supply a comment stating your reason.

Answer (score 1):

Right, the comments under the question I have been making are assuming you want to go directly from the current value to the index, without performing a search.  That is to say, making some inspection of the digits of the entry and translating that to a 1-indexed number.

*Note, this answer is directional and incomplete, just shows the way I would approach the problem.*

Looking at your example, if we treat each entry as composed of 3 digits, **(z_i, y_i, x_i)**, then you get the following sequences:

1. 003; z=0, y=0, x=3
2. 012; z=0, y=1, x=2
3. 021; z=0, y=2, x=1
4. 030; z=0, y=3, x=0
5. 102; z=1, y=0, x=2
6. 111; z=1, y=1, x=1
7. 120; z=1, y=2, x=0
8. 201; z=2, y=0, x=1
9. 210; z=2, y=1, x=0
10. 300; z=3, y=0, x=0

If the max digit is **k** (=3), then:

```
x_i = 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 = k, k-1, ..., 0, k-1, ... 0, ......, 0

y_i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0 = 0, 1, ..., k, 0, ..., k-1, ......, 0

z_i = 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 = k+1 x 0, k x 1, ......., 1 x k
```

As you can see, the **y_i** digit goes up in sequence repetitively, knocking the **z_i** up at the end of each completion.

If you had more digits, the pattern gets more complicated, but still follows a similar pattern.

For **k=4**:

1. 0004
2. 0013
3. 0022
4. 0031
5. 0040
6. 0103
7. 0112
8. 0121
9. 0130
10. 0202
11. 0211
12. 0220
13. 0301
14. 0310
15. 0400
16. 1003
17. 1012
18. 1021
19. 1030
20. 1102
21. 1111
22. 1120
23. 1201
24. 1210
25. 1300
26. 2002
27. 2011
28. 2020
29. 2101
30. 2110
31. 2200
32. 3001
33. 3010
34. 3100
35. 4000

The total entries can be seen from the first or last column, it is the triangle number of the triangle number of `k+1`, in the case of `k=4`.  For `k=3`, it's just the triangle of `k+1`.

[image: Triangle-triangle numbers]

Not having it worked it out, but that pattern might indicate successive summations as the number of digits increases.

There is a pattern still:

`k=3`:

[image: Triangle numbers]

`k=4`:

[image: Triangle squared?]

`k=5`:

[image: Triangle cubed?]

Or in general for the total number of entries in the sequence of length **k**:

[image: Summation sequence total entries]

This knowledge helps give us a hand in finding the scalars for the first digit, and the rest of the problem is effectively a sub problem for `k-1`.  Defeating me at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.binarySearch`.

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List, T)